# Can I miss the catch clause to throw exception to its caller?

Tags: java, exception, finally

What kind of problem may occur for this code?
I think even exception occurs, this code can throw the exception to its caller.
So it does NOT generate any trouble.

How can I improve it?

```
public static void cat(File named) {
  RandomAccessFile input = null;
  String line = null;
  try {
    input = new RandomAccessFile(named, “r”);
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null {
      System.out.println(line);
    }
    return;
  } finally {
    if (input != null) {
      input.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `public static void cat(File named) throws IOException` work?

Comment: it will give a compilation error because you are not handling the checked exception `IOException`

Comment: You need to handle it either using `catch` block or throw it back to the caller by changing the method signature as suggested by @johnchen902

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What kind of problem may occur for this code?

- [public RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#RandomAccessFile%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) **`throws FileNotFoundException`**.
- [public final String readLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readLine%28%29) **`throws IOException`**.
- [public void close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#close%28%29) **`throws IOException`**.

Since **`public class FileNotFoundException
extends IOException`**

You can change your method to:

```
public static void cat(File named) throws IOException
```

And now you don't need a *try-catch* blocks.

And the caller should catch the `exception` thrown by the method.

But why don't you want to `catch` the exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

The code has to throw the IOException - try editing your code with eclipse and you would also get a suggestion to throw the Exception.

Also Java 1.7 has the new concept of "[try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)" - see the try statement below.
The resource used in `try (...)` is closed automatically.

```
public static void cat(File named) throws IOException
{
    try (RandomAccessFile input = new RandomAccessFile(named, "r"))
    {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you do not need a try-catch-finally block if you force the method to throw any exception

Comment: oh? - the "try-with-resource" is used for closing the file - no need to down-vote in case you don't know what you're talking about, right?

Answer (score 0):

add the throws declaration in your method , and then caller of this method should have try catch block for this exception .

```
public static void cat(File named) throws IOException {
      RandomAccessFile input = null;
      String line = null;
      try {
        input = new RandomAccessFile(named, "r");
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null ){
          System.out.println(line);
        }
        return;
      } finally {
        if (input != null) {
          input.close();
        }
      }
    }
  //caller 
   try{
     Class.cat(new File("abc.txt"));
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
      //
    }
```

Comment: you do not need a try-catch-finally block if you force the method to throw any exception

Comment: try with finally to close the resources , catch block is not there.